# Undefined index error when I pass the variable into the $_POST[] variable

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

**This is my html code:**

```
<form method="POST" action=/posts>
      {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputAddress">Attendence Type</label>
     <?php $op="AttendenceZero" ?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="inputPassword4" name="<?php $op ?>" >
    </div>
     </div>
```

**This is my controller where I have to receive the value:**

```
class Employeeleavecontroller extends Controller
{
    //
  public function new()
  {
     $name =$_POST['op'];
     echo $name;
  }
}
```

Comment: name="<?php echo $op; ?>" write like this

Comment: you miss print variable

Comment: What is the value of $op in form ? 
It should be $_POST['whateveropvalueis']

Comment: I need to pass the variable inside the $_POST[] variable

Comment: After reading your question again, I must ask that is difference between `name` and `value` of input element fully clear to you? And where is user defining `$op` and why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive `$_POST['op']` you'll have to have `name="op"` in the form.

`<?php $op ?>` does pretty much nothing. But, if you add in echo:

```
name="<?php echo $op; ?>"
```

You can then receive it:

```
$_POST['AttendenceZero']
```

UPDATE:
If you're still having problems, you should check what you're actually receiving with:

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

And in the end I don't see the reason why you're using a variable for the name. If you're planning to make it dynamic, you'd anyways have to send the dynamic name to the end script, unless if you handle the received data progmatically like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $postName => $postValue) {
    echo "Name: $postName ; Value: $postValue<br />";
}
```

UPDATE 2:

If you really want let user to define the `name` of your POST value, you also need to send the name definition to the end script too. You can use hidden input field for this task, so add this into your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="<?php echo $op;?>">
```

And then in your end script you first receive the fieldName with:

```
$fieldName = $_POST['fieldName'] //$op == "AttendenceZero" or whatever
```

And use it to receive the actual data:

```
$actualData = $_POST[$fieldName];
```

But, all this is pointless if `$op` is not defined once the form is being built. And if so, then you'll have to use for example jQuery to add $op value to the hidden input field when sending the form.

Comment: name="<?php echo $op; ?>" I write the same, but even then it doesn't work

Comment: With `$_POST['AttendenceZero']` ?

Comment: i need to pass variable into the $_POST[] because value like 'AttendenceZero' will mostly user defined

Comment: Ah okay. I'll edit my answer a bit more, one sec. Or actually, what is the reason you need to let user to define the name of a value? Isn't the target to have only value defined by user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

change this line,

`<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="inputPassword4" name="<?php $op ?>" >`

To

`<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="inputPassword4" name="any_name" value="<?php echo $op ?>" >`

And in your controller

`$name = $_POST['any_name']; echo $name;`

So

$name will return AttendenceZero or any user defined value.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds interesting...
It's like **name** of input text field is user defined (dynamic).

There are two ways to handle it.

1) Using Hidden field. (recommended)

2) By Converting to Index Array.

Using hidden field.

```
<form method="POST" action=/posts>
      {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputAddress">Attendence Type</label>
     <?php $op="AttendenceZero" ?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="inputPassword4" name="<?php $op; ?>" >
      <input type="hidden" name="op" value="<?php $op; ?>">
    </div>
     </div>
```

handling hidden field.

```
class Employeeleavecontroller extends Controller
{
    //
  public function new()
  {
     $name = $_POST[$_POST['op']];
     echo $name;
  }
}
```

By converting to index array

```
<form method="POST" action=/posts>
      {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputAddress">Attendence Type</label>
     <?php $op="AttendenceZero" ?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="inputPassword4" name="<?php $op; ?>" >
    </div>
     </div>
```

Handling form request by converting to Index Array.

```
class Employeeleavecontroller extends Controller
{
    //
  public function new()
  {
     $req = array_values($_POST);
     $name = $req[0]; //contain all form data so, find correct index number.
     echo $name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to two change

```
1:  "<?php echo $op; ?>"
```

in controller

```
2: $name =$_POST['AttendenceZero'];
```

and finally its work

Comment: But i need to pass variable into the $_POST[] because value like 'AttendenceZero' will mostly user defined

Comment: what you need and what probleam you face plz define in your question first above ans is your mistack in your code